# Kotlin Native callback to C++ causes memory leak

Tags: kotlin-native

I want to call back data from KN to C++, but there is a memory leak.

According to this official document：https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html#callbacks.

There are 3 cases：

1 invoke StableRef.dispose after I get the value from callback method, but it doesn't seem to work, memory usage continues to grow.

2.if call stableRef.dispose() in kotlin callBack method, and don't call unwrapData in c++,  no memory leak，but I can't get value in c++.

3.If call stableRef.dispose() in kotlin callBack method, and call dispose() in unwrapData, there is an error occurred, then process is  killed.

Demo projects is in the attachments，Example code are as follows.

Kotlin Native example:

```
class CallbackInC(private val _onResult: CPointer<CFunction<(COpaquePointer?) -> Unit>>) : Observer<TestData>() {
    override fun callBack(data: TestData?) {
        data?.let {
            val stableRef = StableRef.create(it)
            val asCPointer = stableRef.asCPointer()
            _onResult.invoke(asCPointer)
//            stableRef.dispose()
        }
    }
}

fun testCallback(callbackInC: CallbackInC, times: Int) {
    for (i in 1..times) {
        callbackInC.callBack(TestData("name$i", i))
    }
}

fun unwrapData(ptr: COpaquePointer): Any? {
    return try {
        val asStableRef = ptr.asStableRef<Any>()
        val get = asStableRef.get()
        asStableRef.dispose()
        get
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}

fun anyToTestData(any: Any?): TestData? {
    if (any is TestData) {
        return any
    }
    return null
}

abstract class Observer<T> {
    abstract fun callBack(data: T?)
}

data class TestData(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

C++ example:

```
emailSdk_ExportedSymbols* sdkSymbols = nullptr;

int count = 0;

void callbackFunc(void* data) {

    emailSdk_kref_kotlin_Any anyData = sdkSymbols->kotlin.root.unwrapData(data);

    emailSdk_kref_TestData testdata = sdkSymbols->kotlin.root.anyToTestData(anyData);

    const char* name = sdkSymbols->kotlin.root.TestData.get_name(testdata);

    //count++;

    std::cout << "callbackFunc name:" << name << std::endl;

}

int main()

{

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    HMODULE hmodule = LoadLibrary(LR"(emailSdk.dll)");

    if (hmodule == nullptr)

    {

        return 1;

    }

    using expot_symbols = emailSdk_ExportedSymbols* (*)(void);

    expot_symbols fpn =(expot_symbols)(GetProcAddress(hmodule, "emailSdk_symbols"));

    sdkSymbols = fpn();

    //test callback

    emailSdk_kref_CallbackInC callbackInC = sdkSymbols->kotlin.root.CallbackInC.CallbackInC(callbackFunc);

    sdkSymbols->kotlin.root.testCallback(callbackInC, 1000000);

}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the demo project?